# how to use assertoff from test to disable assertion in side uvm object

Tags: system-verilog, uvm, system-verilog-assertions

I am looking for way to disable assert in side uvm component for certain test.
Below simple code represent my env, with comment for requirement.
I thought I can use $assertoff.
I can modify uvm component if required additional instrumentation to achieve this.

```
    import uvm_pkg::*;
    `include "uvm_macros.svh"

    class tb_env extends uvm_component;

       `uvm_component_utils(tb_env)

       int exp_val = 0;
       int act_val = 0;

       function new(string name = "tb_env", uvm_component parent = null);
          super.new(name, parent);
       endfunction

       virtual task run_phase (uvm_phase phase);
         super.run_phase(phase);
         phase.raise_objection(this);
         #10us;
         ASRT: assert ( exp_val == act_val) else
           `uvm_error(get_name(), "Error");
         #10us;
         `uvm_info(get_name(), "Done env", UVM_LOW);
         phase.drop_objection(this);
       endtask : run_phase

    endclass

    program tb_run;

    initial
    begin
       tb_env env = new("env");

       // Requirement: Disable assertion env.ASRT with system call $assertoff(...)

       fork
         run_test();
         begin
          #5us;
          env.exp_val = 1;
         end
       join
    end

    endprogram
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can use `$assertoff` for your purpose.

Here is your code without `$assertoff`.

```
class tb_env;
  int exp_val = 0;
  int act_val = 0;

  virtual task run_phase ();
    #10;
    ASRT: assert ( exp_val == act_val) else
      $error("Error");
  endtask : run_phase
endclass

program tb_run;
  tb_env env = new();

  initial
  begin      
     // $assertoff(0, env.run_phase.ASRT);

     fork
       env.run_phase();
       begin
         #5;
         env.exp_val = 1;
         $display("@%0t : exp_val - %0b, act_val - %0b", $time(), env.exp_val, env.act_val);
       end
     join
  end
endprogram

// Output -
@5 : exp_val - 1, act_val - 0
"a.sv", 7: $unit::\tb_env::run_phase .ASRT: started at 10s failed at 10s
        Offending '(this.exp_val == this.act_val)'
Error: "a.sv", 7: $unit.tb_env::run_phase.ASRT: at time 10
Error
$finish at simulation time                   10
```

And here is your code with `$assertoff`.

```
class tb_env;
  int exp_val = 0;
  int act_val = 0;

  virtual task run_phase ();
    #10;
    ASRT: assert ( exp_val == act_val) else
      $error("Error");
  endtask : run_phase
endclass

program tb_run;
  tb_env env = new();

  initial
  begin
     $assertoff(0, env.run_phase.ASRT);

     fork
       env.run_phase();
       begin
         #5;
         env.exp_val = 1;
         $display("@%0t : exp_val - %0b, act_val - %0b", $time(), env.exp_val, env.act_val);
       end
     join
  end
endprogram

// Output -
Stopping new assertion attempts at time 0s: level = 0 arg = $unit::\tb_env::run_phase .ASRT (from inst tb_run (a.sv:17))
@5 : exp_val - 1, act_val - 0
$finish at simulation time                   10
```

Comment: Seems like the code does not work in *irun* but runs fine with *vcs*. Maybe a generalized approach that works on all simulators would be preferable.

Comment: Code is working with irun as well. Hese is the link of edaplayground : https://www.edaplayground.com/x/33Pb. You can try by commenting & uncommenting the `$assertoff` line to compare the results.

Comment: Not working with OP's code (UVM based). [EDAPlayground sample](https://www.edaplayground.com/x/5jHX). Irun error: `Invalid assertion or scope name argument to $assertoff assertion control task`. Runs with vcs though.

Comment: I have modified my code with the given UVM code. And it is working in my case. Please check https://www.edaplayground.com/x/33Pb with Incisive simulator.

Answer (score 2):

I would like to make things simple to understand. So, prefer to use some glue logic for suppressing the assertion.

For some simulators, `$assertoff` **works only on modules and not on classes**, you can **use some guarding flag indicating the enable/disable of assertion**. The assertion will be checked only when the flag is *set*. You can **declare this flag anywhere in the base classes and use the same flag in enabling/disabling assertions from different extended classes**.

One can also develop **a generalized macro for this guarding flag**. The following code disables the assertions by the use of a *guard*. *If* the **guard is a static variable**, then **it can be accessed via *scope resolution*** (::) also.

```
import uvm_pkg::*;
`include "uvm_macros.svh"

`define ASSERT(VAL,ERR) \
  assert(!assert_guard || (VAL))  else begin // If assert_guard=0, then assertion passes without checking other condition \
      `uvm_error(get_name(),ERR); \
end \

class tb_env extends uvm_component;
  `uvm_component_utils(tb_env)
  bit assert_guard;

  int exp_val = 0;
  int act_val = 0;

  function new(string name = "tb_env", uvm_component parent = null);
     super.new(name, parent);
     assert_guard = 1; // by default assertions are on
  endfunction

  virtual task run_phase (uvm_phase phase);
     super.run_phase(phase);
     phase.raise_objection(this);
     #10us;
     ASRT: `ASSERT( exp_val == act_val, "Error");       
     #10us;
     `uvm_info(get_name(), "Done env", UVM_LOW);
     phase.drop_objection(this);
  endtask : run_phase

endclass

module tb_run;
 initial begin
   tb_env env = new("env");
   env.assert_guard = 0;
   //tb_env::assert_guard = ; // If assert_guard was static
   //$assertoff(0,env.run_phase.ASRT); // Works only for VCS
   fork
     run_test();
     begin
      #5us;
      env.exp_val = 1;
     end
   join
 end
endmodule
// Output:
UVM_INFO @ 0: reporter [RNTST] Running test ...
UVM_INFO testbench.sv(31) @ 20000: env [env] Done env
```

As an alternative approach, one can also make use of `disable` statement of **disabling deffered assertion**. But in this case, **one needs to know exact time when the assertion is to be fired**. Refer to IEEE [1800-2012 Section 16.4.4](https://standards.ieee.org/getieee/1800/download/1800-2012.pdf) for more information about this approach.

Answer (score 1):

The `$assertoff` system task can turn assertions off in specific modules, but not specific classes or objects. So, you'll have to do it manually by modifying your `tb_env` class.